# How to specify OpenAI Organization ID in Microsoft AutoGen?

Tags: python, openai-api

In order to create a "config_list" for OpenAI in [Microsoft AutoGen](https://github.com/microsoft/autogen) I do the following:

```py
import os
config_list = [{
  'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo-1106',
  'api_key': os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
}]
```

How does one specify an [OpenAI organization ID](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/organization-optional)?

P.S. - I didn't find an appropriate tag for Microsoft's AutoGen so I just used openai-api. Do we need to create one?

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and found that any parameters put into the `config_list` entry are passed right along to the OpenAI `Client`. So thus I can specify the organization like so:

```py
import os
config_list = [{
  'model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo-1106',
  'api_key': os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
  'organization': os.getenv("OPENAI_ORG_ID") or os.getenv("OPENAI_ORGANIZATION"),
}]
```

I verified by looking at the [Usage](https://platform.openai.com/usage) page and saw the requests increase for the appropriate organization.